# Check whether second partial derivatives are equal at (0,0)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Check whether it is true that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(0,0)$ for function:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y^3}{x^2+y^2} \ \ when \ \ (x,y) \neq  (0,0) \\ 0 \ \ when \ \ (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$

Would it be enough to calculate the derivate of f with regards to x and then calculate it with regards to y, and calculate the limit when respectively: y and x approaches 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $x\neq 0, y \neq 0$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{y^2}}$$
let $$g(x,y)=\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{y^2}$$ then $$f(x,y)=\frac1g$$
$$g_x=-2x^{-3}$$ $$g_y=-2y^{-3}$$ $$g_{xy}=0$$ $$g_{yx}=0$$ $$f_x=-g^{-2}g_x$$
$$f_{xy}=g^{-3}g_yg_x-g^{-2}g_{xy}=g^{-3}g_yg_x$$ similarly, $$f_{yx}=g^{-3}g_yg_x$$

Rest part might be more tedious as we need to show $f_x$, $f_y$, $f_xy$ and $f_yx$ with x and y equals 0.

Comment: why do wee need to check $f_x$ and $f_y$ when x and y equals 0? Isn't it enought to check the limit of $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ when x and y goes to 0? (and since they are the same i need to check it only for one of them)

Comment: I was thinking $f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}$ might not continuous. If it is continuous, you can do that. I will add that up when I get time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any doubt about the question, you should calculate both derivative to prove to yourself that that are equivalent operations. The operations are symmetric.  You should check this [link](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~mradclif/teaching/Math10C/LectureNotes/second_order_partial_derivatives.pdf) here that might clear things up for you.

Also the notation used describes the derivative at the point $(0,0)$ rather than the limit as $x$ or $y$ tends to $0$.